# Convert a double to a QString

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing a program in Qt. I want to convert a `double` into a `QString` in C++.

Comment: @Macmade, I am new to QT and CPP. But i have a java code so i want to convert into cpp for qt application.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Use QString's number method (docs are [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#number-2)):

```
double valueAsDouble = 1.2;
QString valueAsString = QString::number(valueAsDouble);
```

Comment: This one is annoying since precision is fixed.

Comment: CAUTION: That call may lead to loss of precision. I did that same call once and I got 6.84442e+06 from 6844418.0, for example. They were metric UTM coordinates, so that 10m loss was unacceptable. Please, do be careful depending on the application. I used   `std::stringstream ss; 
ss << std::setprecision( 12 ); 
ss << (double)value;`  *How do I markdown code blocks in this thing?*

Comment: @PauloCarvalho Use [QLocale::FloatingPointShortest](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html#FloatingPointPrecisionOption-enum) (available since Qt 5.7)

Comment: Note: For the 'g' and 'G' formats, the precision represents the maximum number of significant digits (trailing zeroes are omitted).
For example 1.0 will be converted to "1"

Answer (score 18):

Instead of `QString::number()` i would use [`QLocale::toString()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html#toString-6), so i can get locale aware group seperatores like german "1.234.567,89".

Comment: Not always. I need to convert to US system (48.1), and this would mess things.

Answer (score 15):

Building on @Kristian's answer, I had a desire to display a fixed number of decimal places.  That can be accomplished with other arguments in the `QString::number(...)` function. For instance, I wanted 3 decimal places:

```
double value = 34.0495834;
QString strValue = QString::number(value, 'f', 3);
// strValue == "34.050"
```

The `'f'` specifies decimal format notation (more info [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#argument-formats), you can also specify scientific notation) and the `3` specifies the precision (number of decimal places).  Probably already linked in other answers, but more info about the `QString::number` function can be found [here in the `QString` documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html)

Answer (score 9):

You can use arg(), as follow:

```
double dbl = 0.25874601;
QString str = QString("%1").arg(dbl);
```

This overcomes the problem of: "Fixed precision" at the other functions like: setNum() and number(), which will generate random numbers to complete the defined precision

Comment: According to the doc `The conversion uses the default locale`, the precision is also -1 by default instead of 6 for `QString::number`

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html)

Quote:

> QString provides many functions for
>   converting numbers into strings and
>   strings into numbers. See the [arg()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#arg)
>   functions, the [setNum()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#setNum) functions, the
>   [number()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#number) static functions, and the
>   [toInt()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#toInt), [toDouble()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#toDouble), and similar
>   functions.