# converting and formatting double to QString

Tags: c++, string, qt

I am trying to append a double to a QString in such that `12.34` be displayed as `012.34`. So if I have these two variables:

```
double num = 12.34;
QString str = "literal ";
```

I want to append the number to the string so it results in `literal 012.34`.

**EDIT:**
The format needs to be xxx.xx, i.e. three before the decimal and two after, always. It is kind of a requirement. I could probably simply append the zero before the number, then I would need to check if the number is less than 100; I don't think that is the best way to go with, I might be wrong.

I am simulating some kind of climate chamber. The double number represents a temperature result which changes between -40 and 150. I will write the constructed string to a serial device, and a program on the other device will expect this format to do something with it. I am new to Qt and not so good at C++ either, kind of learning as I make this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert double to QString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940846/convert-double-to-qstring)

Comment: Can't you simply prepend `0` to the string. Please explain the logic behind that: why you need the leading `0` character?

Comment: @vahancho I was under the impression he probably wanted a generic way to format doubles, like `%3.2f` for `printf`.  I agree that he probably needs to specify more detail about what he wants.

Comment: @dwcanillas, hm, but prepending `0` to the left of a decimal number does not make any sense. Let's see, what the OP really needs.

Comment: Do you always want (at least) three digits on the left of decimal point? Or do you always just one the preceding 0 (so you could just have `"literal 0" + QString::number(num)`)? Please clarify your exact output requirements.

Comment: Thank you all for the help, I learned some things from the suggestions and conversations. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
QString{ "literal %1" }.arg( 12.34, 6, 'g', -1, '0' )
// Returns "literal 012.34"
```

This will always give you a minimum of 6 characters of output (5 digits plus a decimal point, or 6 digits).  Alternatively:

```
QString{ "literal %1" }.arg( 12.34, 6, 'f', 2, '0' )
// Returns "literal 012.34"
```

Will always give you a minimum of 6 characters output where there always two digits after the decimal place.

**Note** The braced constructor calls require C++11 or above, switch to using brackets if you can't use that version of the standard.

Comment: @darron Example added.

Comment: @darron C++11 object instantiation has moved to using braces to explicitly avoid the "most vexing parse" problem.  Herbs explains the style push here: http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/

Comment: @darron Done. When did answering simple questions get so hard?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77019/discussion-between-darron-and-cmannett85).

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE

I suggest you [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#arg-20) one to read.

```
QString zeroString( "0" );
QString( "literal %1%2" ).arg( zeroString ).arg( 12.34, 0, 'f', 2 );
```

But you should specify why to add the zeroString.

Comment: This will not compile. Second parameter is not the format char.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Second parameter is for example 0.

Comment: If you are going for this as an answer, why not just `QString( "literal 0%2" ).arg( 12.34, 0, 'f', 2 )`?

Comment: I was thinking about that Sime has an algorithm with which he decides if he wants that '0' or not (or maybe more than one '0').

Comment: QString("literal %1%2").arg(num<100 ? "0" :"").arg(num,0,'f',2);  ... but QString("literal %1").arg(num,6,'f',2,'0'); is the right answer, since a method to do that exists.